# Как составить sql запрос на php если условий очень много?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, запрос

Имеется фильтр с множеством данных:

1. цена: минимальная,максимальная
2. кол-во комнат: студия,1,2,3,4+
3. отделка: без отделки, черновая, чистовая
4. сдача объекта: 2017,2018,2019,2020
5. варианты оплаты: рассрочка, ипотека, мат капитал
6. площадь квартиры: мин, макс
7. класс: эконом,комфорт,бизнес,премиум

Каждое значение фильтра может быть как выбрано так и нет. В БД хранятся данные в разных взаимосвязанных таблицах. Собственно вопрос, как учесть все параметры при составлении SQL запроса?

Comment: Данные по выборке в разных взаимосвязанных таблицах? И что именно Вы хотите в SQL запросе видеть? Получить инфу по каждому параметру, или отправить в БД заказ собранный из параметров?

Comment: Проверяйте каждые данные на пустоту и в соответствии с этими данными формируйте sql запрос к вашей БД

Comment: Нужно выборку сделать объектов которые подходят по выбранным параметрам и вывести пользователю, проверять каждый на пустоту то не проблема, а вот как составить запрос учитывая не пустые параметры?

Comment: @ДанилШуваев дописываете в условие запроса `where` в виде: `where 1=1 and (дальше условия, например:) rooms in (1, 2, 3, 4) and class in ('econom', 'comfort') and ...`

Answer (score 1):

Подключайте дополнительное условие "`AND (OR) WHERE`" в зависимости от указанных данных.
Аналогично реализовано во многих ORM (Doctrine например), по этому примеру можно сделать свой метод. 
Итого получим:
    Класс формирующий запрос, где все условия WHERE зависят от свойства `$where`, которое в свою очередь модифицируется методами `orWhere($condition)` и `andWhere($condition)`
Итого запрос внутри новоиспеченного билдера запросов будет выглядеть

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table " . $this->where . " LIMIT 10000";
```